# How to solve invalid input syntax for type double precision

Tags: python, postgresql

I try to load csv data into postgres. The creating table part is fine. But when I try to load data from csv, it got error. My code and error are attached below. Is %s wrong?

```
import psycopg2
import csv 

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port="5432", database="postgres", user="postgres", password="*******")
print "Opened database successfully"

cur = conn.cursor()     
cur.execute('''create table calls_aapl("Ask" float,"Bid" float,"Change" float,"ContractSymbol" varchar(50),"ImpliedVolatility" float,"LastPrice" float,
                  "LastTradeDate" date,"OpenInterest" int,"PercentChange" float,"Strike" float,"Volume" int);''')
print "Table created successfully"

reader = csv.reader(open('D:/python/Anaconda/AAPL_Data/Calls.csv', 'r'))

for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    print(i, row)
    if i == 0: continue


    cur.execute('''
        INSERT INTO "calls_aapl"(
            "Ask", "Bid", "Change", "ContractSymbol", "ImpliedVolatility", "LastPrice", "LastTradeDate", "OpenInterest", "PercentChange", "Strike", "Volume"
        ) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''', row
    )

conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

Error:

```
(0, ['Ask', 'Bid', 'Change', 'ContractSymbol', 'LastPrice', 'LastTradeDate', 'OpenInterest', 'PercentChange', 'PercentImpliedVolatility', 'Strike', 'Volume'])
(1, ['41.7', '39.75', '1.15', 'AAPL180803C00150000', '41.05', '7/31/2018', '52', '2.88', '154.59', '150', '6'])
DataError: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "7/31/2018"
LINE 4: ...1.7','39.75','1.15','AAPL180803C00150000','41.05','7/31/2018...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Well `7/31/2018` isn't a double precision number, it´s a date. Edit: Sorry, that wasn't very informative. It looks to me like your `LastTradeDate` column expects a double, is that correct?

Comment: @Plasma where I should modify from the code? Do I need to give format for date?

Comment: Compare the column values from `row` to the column names in the insert statement. (e.g. `LastPrice` vs. `7/31/2018`)

Comment: @Plasma It a date (e.g.2018/07/31) not a double. That's why I don't understand.

Comment: @clemens Sorry, I don't get it. What you mean?

Comment: @JJL Yes, that is indeed the problem. What your error is trying to tell us is that the DB attempts to insert a date string, i.e. `7/31/2018`, into a column that only accept values of type double precision, e.g. `3.14`. You'd either have to change your `LastTradeDate` column to accept date strings (and then you can continue to provide values like `7/31/2018`), or change the format of your date to a double precision number, which the DB could accept, but I guess that makes less sense.

Comment: @Plasma Thank you. How can I change my date column to accept date strings? I tried a lot of times, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Actually, you've set the right type (I didn't see it before now, sorry). What does your `row` look like?

Comment: You shouldn't change your column definitions. E. g. a column named `LastPrice` which contains dates will make no sense in general. You should reorder the columns such that names and values match.

Comment: @clemens No, the LastPrice column doesn't contain dates. They are separate.

Comment: @Plasma row means to loop through every single row from the csv file to insert them into the postgres

Comment: But why you're trying to insert a date into the `LastPrice` column?

Comment: @clemens I know what you mean, sorry. So I should start from row 1?

Comment: @clemens I just tried to skip the header row, but it still has double precision problem.

Comment: @JJL what I meant is what does a row look like, could you give us an example? As @clemens points out, you may be trying to insert your date into the `LastPrice` column, which doesn't accept dates, but floats. What you're inserting where depends on the order of values in `row`, which is why we need to see what it looks like.

Comment: @Plasma Thank you for pointing out. The problem is the column order. I didn't notice that. The code is fine, just need to change order.

Comment: @clemens Thank you for your help. I figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%s` is ok because PostgreSQL can cast strings to numbers in an `INSERT`.

Your problem is a different one. Your `INSERT` statement specifies a column `"ImpliedVolatility"` (too late for a warning against mixed case identifiers) which is not in the data.

This causes the fifth column (labeled `LastPrice` to be inserted into `"ImpliedVolatility"` and the next column (labeled `LastTradeDate`) to be inserted into `"LastPrice"`.

The former of these is wrong but works, because both `"LastPrice"` and `"ImpliedVolatility"` are `float^H^H^H^H^Hdouble precision`, but the latter fails because it tries to insert a date string into a `double precision` column.

Omit the column `"ImpliedVolatility"` from the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice my order of columns has changed.

Answer (score 0):

its just about typo i think,
you should equalize the table column to your insert query.
That "LastTradeDate" is inserted to "LastPrice" which is which is not the right column

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually occurs when your column headers and values aren't matched up properly. Try checking to see if the number of values specified are the same and of similar data types.